# C# Is it possible to go to given line of from one file to another?

Tags: c#, class, oop, goto

I want to ask is it possible to go to given line of from one class to another in C#.Here is an example of what is my idea :

```
public class Class1
{
  public void MethodFromClass1()
  {
     // Doing some operations before to go in the another class
     goto: PlaceToGo
     // Doing some operations after going in the another class
  }
}

public class Class2
{
  public void MethodFromClass2()
  {
     PlaceToGo:
        Console.WriteLine("Print something.");
  }
}
```

Comment: If you need to do this, then you're going about it all wrong.  C# is a procedural and object-oriented language.  You should familiarize yourself with those paradigms.

Comment: Based on your comments in the code, you just want a normal method call, rather than typical `goto` behaviour of just going somewhere and not coming back.

Comment: I don't want to start the next "goto is evil" discussion, but what you are trying here is against everything C#. Just call MethodFromClass2. Why goto?

Comment: Also it's not possible - [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664758(v=vs.71).aspx): *"If a label with the given name does not exist in the current function member, or if the `goto` statement is not within the scope of the label, a compile-time error occurs."*

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to use `goto` operator. You should avoid it. In your case you can do it by another way(create instance of `Class2` and call its method):

```
public void MethodFromClass1()
{
     Class2 class2 = new Class2();
     class2.MethodFromClass2();
}
```

Also, if you even jump to this class, the object might not be created already so it doesn't makes sense.

Comment: Why would it not be a good practice ? It the feature exists it's for a reason. Please provide some arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can familiarize yourself with goto : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx

"Jumping" to a different class does not make too much sense to me since it was never "constructed" prior to that. In any case, I would advice you not to use this technique in C# as it makes the core difficult track and understand.

Answer (score 0):

One of few legitimate usages of `goto` may be in a `switch` statement:

```
// Though this is a very stupid example!
int number = 0;

switch (number)
{
    case 0:
       Console.Write("hello ");
       goto case 1;

    case 1:
       Console.WriteLine("world!");
       break;
}
```

BTW, I've never found myself using `goto`, and your use case is just an absurdity.

Perhaps what you want is an *event*, which is no other thing than broadcasting a *heya! I'm about to do something, anyone?*, and some *listeners* perform actions as an answer to the whole *event*. See the following code snippet to get further details:

```
public class Class1
{
  private event EventHandler _BeforeDoingStuff;
  private event EventHandler BeforeDoingStuff 
  {
      add { _BeforeDoingStuff += value; }
      remove { _BeforeDoingStuff -= value; }
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
     // Do some stuff
     // Then fire the event
     _BeforeDoingStuff?.Invoke(EventArgs.Empty);
     // Continue with more stuff after firing the event
  }
}

public class Class2
{
  public Class2(Class1 class1) 
  {
      class1.BeforeDoingStuff += (sender, e) => 
      {
           Console.WriteLine("I did some stuff in the middle of Class1.DoStuff!");
      }
  }
}

Class1 class1 = new Class1();
Class2 class2 = new Class2(class1);
```

Learn more about events in C# [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This should depict what you would want.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class FirstMethod
    {
        public void ExecuteThisNow(int number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This number: " + number + " is going to be skipped over");
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class SecondMethod
    {
        private int lengthOfLoop = 10;

        private int i = 0;

        public void RunTheLoop()
        {
            for (this.i = 0; i < this.lengthOfLoop; i++)
            {
                if (this.i == 5)
                {
                    goto ExecuteFirstMethod;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            ExecuteFirstMethod: FirstMethod first = new FirstMethod();
            first.ExecuteThisNow(this.i);
        }
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var second = new SecondMethod();
            second.RunTheLoop();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, such a code smells bad and it's really bad practice. But if you are playing a simple game/test you can do it like this:

```
public interface IGoTo
{
    void Goto(params object[] p);
}

public class CalleeClass : IGoTo
{
    public void Goto(params object[] p)
    {
        this.MethodFromCallee();
    }

    public void MethodFromCallee()
    {

    }
}

public class CallerClass
{
    public void MethodFromCaller(IGoTo g)
    {
        g.Goto();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var callee = new CalleeClass();
    new CallerClass().MethodFromCaller(callee);
}
```